# KnockoutJS: Update/Insert data to a viewModel using mapping

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time now. I couldn't find anything that addresses this problem, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

The problem:
I have data from a JSON API comming in, with an nested array/object structure. I use mapping to initially fill the model with my data. To update this, I want to extend the model if new data arrives, or update the existing data.

As far as I found out, the mapping option key, should do this trick for me, but I might have misunderstood the functionality of the mapping options.

I've boiled down the problem to be represented by this example:

```js
var userMapping = {
    key: function(item) {
        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.id);
    }
};

// JSON call replaced with values
var viewModel = {
    users: ko.mapping.fromJS([], userMapping)
};

// Should insert new - new ID?
ko.mapping.fromJS([{"id":1,"name":"Foo"}, {"id":2,"name":"Bar"}], userMapping, viewModel.users);

// Should only update ID#1 - same ID?
ko.mapping.fromJS([{"id":1,"name":"Bat"}], userMapping, viewModel.users);

// Should insert new - New ID?
ko.mapping.fromJS([{"id":3,"name":"New"}, {"id":4,"name":"New"}], userMapping, viewModel.users);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikaelbr/gDjA7/

As you can see, the first line inserts the data. All good. But when I try to update, it replaces the content. The same for the third mapping; it replaces the content, instead of extening it.

Am I using it wrong? Should I try to extend the content "manually" before using mapping?

**Edit Solution:**
I solved this case by having a second helper array storing all current models. On new data i extended this array, and updated the view model to contain the accumulated items.

On update (In my case a WebSocket message), I looped through the models, changed the contents of the item in question, and used method valueHasMutated() to give notice of changed value to the Knockout lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at your example code the mapping plugin is behaving exactly as I would expect it to. When you call `fromJS` on a collection you are effectively telling the mapping plugin this is the new contents of that collection. For example:

On the second line, How could it know whether you were updating or whether you had simply removed id:2?

I can't find any mention of a suitable method that treats the data as simply an update, although you could add one. Mapped arrays come with some helpful methods such as `mappedIndexOf` to help you find particular items. If you receive an update data set simply loop through it, find the item and update it with a mapping.fromJS call to that particular item. This can easily be generalized into reusable method.

Comment: Any thoughts on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397054/knockout-js-mapping-keys-and-kendo-ui-grid

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ko.mapping.updateFromJS()` to update existing values. However, it does not add new values so that would be a problem in your instance. Take a look at the link below for more details.

[Using updateFromJS is replacing values when it should be adding them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086003/knockoutjs-using-updatefromjs-replacing-values-when-it-should-be-adding)

Comment: The updateFromJS() method was removed in august 2011. https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/commit/bff3c1864a5fd45289933b35de1ef70af4aed6b5

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should first collect all data into a list or array and then apply the mapping to that list. Otherwise you are going to overwrite the values in your viewModel.