# KnockoutJS - Update ViewModel / Mapping Plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

### How can i update the complete viewModel ?

1. On page load i get a Model and convert that using `ko.mapping.fromJS(myObject)` to a viewModel.
2. If the user clicks a button i want to get updated data from the server
3. Now i want to apply theese updates

If i use `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);` it updates the ui perfectly. But it adds the same events again. So if the user clicks the button, the event gets fired twice, third and so on.

### Question

#### What is a good way to update my complete viewModel. Maybe i remove the bindings and apply them again ? (how to do this).

### Sample

```
var viewModel;

function update() 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        type: "GET",
        statusCode: {
            200: function (data) {
                 viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
                 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            }
        }
    });    
}

// first call after page load
update();

// user click
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    update(); 
});
```

### Update

> **Steve Greatrex** Could you post your custom binding implementation?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.domBinding = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        viewModel.domElement = element;
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        viewModel.domElement = element;
    },
};
```

Comment: Could you post your viewModel code as well?  Is `domElement` an observable?

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the 'Specifying the update target' on the [mapping documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), you can specify a target for the mapping.

This should mean that you can say:

```
if (!viewModel)
   viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
else
   ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModel);
```

This way you will create a view model on the initial load, then update that view model for any subsequent loads.

Comment: +1 This works nice. But one thing does not work. I have a customBinding and this does not get updated (stopped working). Any idea ?

Comment: Could you post your custom binding implementation?

Comment: @dknaack: Make sure you don't call `ko.applyBindings` a second time. You should only ever call that once per view.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you then data-bind? ex: data-bind="viewModel" ?

Comment: @Vyache you wouldn't need to change your data bindings after the update - they would automatically be updated

Comment: @SteveGreatrex gotcha, I'm still having issues with this. I'm using GET, no data at the start, knockout tells my model is undefined. I created a Model for it and tried your method, but my model never gets updated.

Comment: You'll need some form of data up-front to allow you to bind to the initial values.  I would suggest creating an "empty" data object that you use with `ko.mapping.fromJS` as soon as the page loads, then populate it with real data once the AJAX call completes

Answer (score 3):

Using mapping plugin I did this

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(JsonResponse, myObservable());
```

That's all.